# how can I deploy react app with frontend and backend folder on iis server?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, iis

I have a react project that consists of frontend and backend files. I read that when running command "npm run build", it can be done. However, as I understand it only works for a single folder structured projects. How can my project be deployed with 2 folders ?

Comment: This link should help you: [https://codedamn.com/news/reactjs/how-to-connect-react-with-node-js](https://codedamn.com/news/reactjs/how-to-connect-react-with-node-js).

Comment: Thank you, but they are already connected. I just don't know how it can be deployed.

Comment: If you want to deploy 2 projects you can also refer to this link: [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/javascript/tutorial-asp-net-core-with-react?view=vs-2022](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/javascript/tutorial-asp-net-core-with-react?view=vs-2022).